# Changing tomcat port in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am creating a Docker image using dockerfile build, where my base image is Tomcat 8.0:jre8. Now in the dockerfile I want to specify a custom port instead of 8080 and expose a custom port outside the docker container.

Can anyone guide me how this can be done?

Answer (score 3):

The port used inside the container has nothing to do with docker. This is configured in the Tomcat configuration files.

You can map the port used internally to a port on the host with the `--publish` (or `-p` for short) option of the `docker run` command when you start the container.

```
docker run --publish=hostport:containerport ...
```

Comment: `FROM tomcat:8.0-jre8
#install npm and bower
RUN echo "Installing NPM"
RUN  apt-get update
RUN  apt-get -y install  nodejs
RUN  apt-get -y install npm

RUN echo "Installing Bower"
RUN  npm -g install bower
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

#install git
RUN apt-get -y install git`

I m creating my dockerfile like this wherein along with tomcat am installing npm,bower,git and my custom js libraries. 
How to specify the host port here since I don't run the docker ,I just want to use the created image?

Comment: The port tomcat listens on is configured in the `conf/server.xml` file. See the tomcat documentation for details. That said, I don't see why you need to change it (it can be mapped to any host port). Also what do you mean with "I don't run the docker"? You must create a container based on an image to run it.